# Why is this not a syntax / compile time error?

Tags: typescript

I accidentally typed `:` instead of `=` at line 2 of this piece of code.

Why is this valid Typescript? Shouldn't colon expect a known Type declaration on a property definition?

I am certain that there is somewhere in the TS spec that allows it, but **what is the purpose**?

```
export class CategoriesService {
  private _url : "http://localhost:3000/someurl"; // ???????????

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getData(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._url).map(res => res.json()); //fails here, as _url is undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: Tested it a bit since I could not found an explanation. Seems like it just assigns as a type. So `_url` can only contain the string
 `"http://localhost:3000/someurl"`. Anything else will error the compiler. Besides that `_url` is now also not initiated so `undefined` seems right. Also you're missing `this` before the get request (this._url).

Comment: Correct, I was missing this; fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These types are [String Literal Types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), which are useful in the context of union types, especially in [discriminated unions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) that can be used to simulate pattern matching found in functional programming languages.